# PHP - array change input from string into number when passing into class function

Tags: php, arrays, string-conversion

I am trying to pass array of 4 strings into function but inside that function it change third string into number 1, any clue why that happened and how to prevent that?

Here is some code I use for that:
Array I pass in:

```
$lista = array("user_info","county", $_POST['lokacja'], "ID_hrabstwa");             
$ID_hrabstwa = VarGetter::getVar("IDHRABSTWA",$lista);
```

and function that take the array:

```
static public function getVar($varToGet,$data)
{
  $DM = new DatabaseManager;
  $column = array($data[0]);
  $where = array($data[1]=>$data[2]);
  $ID_hrabstwa = $DM->selectData($data[3], $column, $where);
  return $ID_hrabstwa[0]['ID_hrabstwa'];
}
```

I also try to create a variable to hold that $_POST[] but no results either.
I will appropriate any kind of clue/explanation what am I doing wrong, why that happen.

Comment: What value is the $_POST['lokacja'] variable starting with?

Comment: PHP is a loosely-typed language; the engine is free to interpret your data as any type that seems appropriate. You can override its decisions via explicit [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

Comment: Value of POST is a string name of county from list, I check before I pass it into function and its display correctly

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: i try that type juggling and casting that to a string but still no results, any other hints - please

Comment: Please provide more information about the problem. How do you know that the value is being converted into an integer? What is the value output of `print_r($_POST['lokacja'])` before calling `getVar()`? What is the output of `print_r($data[2])` in `getVar()`? What SQL query is produced by `selectData()`? Check each of these steps to determine the point at which your value is converted to an integer, and then we can discuss how to cast the value to a string if needed.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins: output of %_POST['lokacja'] is a string that it should be I check that but when I print_r Either whole array $data or just The third element of that array, which should be string, in the getVar method I some magically get number 1 each time, maybe it is representation of boolean not an integer. My point is that before I call method value of variable is as should be but inside function it change and I dont know why that happen and what to do to fix that